# Any idea why I can't edit a file even if I run vim as root?

Tags: terminal, permission

I am on OSX Mojave and I have a file with the following permissions:

`-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   2.7K Jan 31 04:32 settings.json`

I did a `sudo su -` and now `whoami` returns `root`.

Any idea why I still can't save any change I make to this file? When I try to `:w` in vim I get `"settings.json" E212: Can't open file for writing`.

Comment: My first thought is either SIP or TCC, two systems which have the power to "override" root. The former can be fully disabled. What is this file? Is it a system file or a file you created?

Comment: What is the output of: `ls -le@ /path/to/settings.json`

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  2755 Feb  1 08:25 settings.json`

Comment: it's a file in the folder of Bitdefender antivirus

Comment: @daniels please post the output of `ls -lhoOd /path/to/settings.json`

Comment: @daniels and the output of `lsof +D /path/to/settings.json` as well

Comment: `ls -lhoOd settings.json` => `-rw-r--r--  1 root  -  2.7K Feb  1 08:25 settings.json`

Comment: `lsof +D settings.json` => `lsof: WARNING: not a directory: settings.json
lsof 4.89
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvV] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.`

Comment: @daniels sorry, just a typo, should be like `lsof /path/to/settings.json`

Comment: Strangely `root# lsof settings.json` does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said in a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350254/any-idea-why-i-cant-edit-a-file-even-if-i-run-vim-as-root#comment459926_350254) , it's a file in Bitdefender antivirus's folder, so there is a chance that the software is blocking anybody to access writing the file.

Have you tried to stop Bitdefender to unlock the file ?

Otherwise, if you try to copy the file, then modify it and put it back in the folder, did it works ?